# Creating a limited drop-down List

Tags: excel, list

## So say I have a table x by y entries.

X is far too great, or changes often enough, that making X additional tables/lists/named ranges is absurd.
However, I need to make a drop-down list of **some** of y.

Specifically:

`Name  |  A   |  B   |  C   | ..
Yannis| 20   |Yellow| Green| ..
Mirrah| 400  |Purple|Yellow| ..
.
.
.`

I need a drop-down select of `Name` to change the options in a different drop-down list, which is based off of B & C.
Normally you can do this with either a Filter or INDIRECT(). However, it is beyond unreasonable to create a unique table, or name define, for each entry in X.

It **is** possible to create a table with all the possible entries for B & C, if there was a way to filter a named define for a list based off of the first table (using vlookup(), most likely)

In layman's terms: I need `list 1` to filter `list 2` where `list 1` is either enormous or subject to constant change.

Gah, so this:

```
=INDIRECT("'InfoDump'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(C5,PkmList,0)+25,10))
```

put into the data validation list works, however it's only one entry, and I need 3.
simply adding commas and copies causes error messages.

The **one** entry that this supplies is correctly referenced (dynamically) from the table without any need for more tables/namedRanges.

C5 is where the first list is
PkmList is the NamedRange for the first column of the Table
+25 'cause the table starts at A25 (column title)
10 referencing the first of 3 columns I need in the second list.

Comment: I guess it should be pointed out that this is designed to work in copy-paste visually appealing blocks, where the tables are exclusively placed on a different sheet (with the goal of only being updated, not used). Hence the need to filter the list directly, rather than filtering a table by 'list 1' and dynamically naming it for 'list 2'.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a dropdown list (Validation>List) that changes depending upon a prior selection (in another dropdown list)?

If so, I can help.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that Indirect() is kinda unfeasible, since the first list has 700+ entries.

Comment: Just re-read your question...
I had in mind setting up the second dropdown list with something like this:
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(Name,NameLookup,2,FALSE))
 which may be what you didn't want to do? Do I have that correct?

Comment: =indirect(vlookup($cell$Ref,TableName,#)) gives me the usual data validation error of "We found something wrong with this, did you not mean to type a function?"
Referencing to the op, I want a second drop-down that has B and C as options, derived from the first drop-down that selects 'Name'.

Comment: Hmmm... I meant to put the =INDIRECT(VLOOKUP...) formula inside the data validation range. I have done this plenty of times, so something is not correct. If you have done that then I'm not sure... Do you want to email me your file? stephenjbarrettVIP@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay!
After some experimentation, this accomplishes what I was looking for:

```
=INDIRECT("'InfoDump'!" & (ADDRESS(MATCH(C5,PkmList,0)+25,10)) & ":" & ((ADDRESS(MATCH(C5,PkmList,0)+25,12))))
```

or, in some different terms:

```
=INDIRECT("'sheetName'!" & (ADDRESS(MATCH(DropDownOne,DropDownOneCriteria,0)+(AdjustRow),(AdjustColumn))) & ":" & ((ADDRESS(MATCH(DropDownOne,DropDownOneCriteria,0)+(AdjustRow),(AdjustColumn)))))
```

Data validation hates logic.

-

In the most basic sense:

Match(a,b,c) gets the location of 'a' in 'b' (c is the same as vlookup's exact match option)

Address(row,column) gets the "j26" address, you can (as I did) adjust from where you found the match. (in my case, 25 down 'casue the table actually started at A25, but the list started at '1'; then 10 - 12 across for the 3 options I needed to list)

indirect(txt) turns this into a list. more or less. use "'sheetName'!" for referencing a different sheet.

-

So in the end this gives you a "=A2:A4" in the Data validation bar, based on another list. Same as using the popular work around that is the fruit vegetable cabbage example, but this doesn't require you to make multiple named ranges. (Which means it works for a single large changing table).